# TCPDF plugin css functionality

Tags: php, css

I'd like to export pdf with css to set

```
border-radius:50% or background-image:url('../');
```

I can do styling work like `text-alignment`, `background-color`, but how can I set `border-radius` or `background image`.

Anyhelp would be appreciate.

Comment: TCPDF has very limited support for CSS styling. I just don't think, that `border-radius` is supported. AFAIK, wkhtmltopdf deals much better with HTML&CSS than TCPDF.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how can I do that then? Could you recommend other plugins which is supporting that one pls?

Comment: As I mentioned in edited comment, I would suggest using wkhtmltopdf, but it's not written in PHP, therefore it needs to be installed on host machine in first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'd like to export dynamic data. but I think wkhtmltopdf is a tool to export as pdf

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. wkhtmltopdf just coverts html to pdf. It doesn't matter, how you generate the html. So my solution is to generate  the html with your dynamic data and the execute wkhtmltopdf from PHP level.

Comment: I'd like to use php functions to export as pdf file.

Comment: You can use one of available PHP wrappers which will call wkhtmltopdf for you. But still it needs to be installed separately. There's no good library written in PHP that will do this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCPDF extension has a very little css support.

Currently, only the following CSS attributes are supported:

- font-family
- font-size
- font-weight
- font-style
- color
- background-color
- text-decoration
- width
- height
- text-align

Other tags will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you recommend any other plugin to export as pdf file with those styles like border-radius or background-image pls

Comment: frankly not sure, i am working with TCPDF only with all the limitations as this is the best i got as of now...